# Python Tkinter not working. Name error

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

Really simple code, but not working using tkinder in Python.

This code has been copied just as seen in a video tutorial, so I think it could be any config:

```
from tkinter import*

root=Tk()

miFrame=Frame(root, width=500, height=400)

miFrame=pack()

Label(miFrame, text="Hola alumnos de Python", fg="red", font=("Comic Sans 
MS", 18)).place(x=100, y=200)

root.mainloop()
```

The error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "Prueba2.py", line 7, in 
>           miFrame=pack()
>       NameError: name 'pack' is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `miFrame=pack()` with `miFrame.pack()`

Answer (score 0):

The row **`miFrame=pack()`** is an attempt to assign a symbol **`miFrame`** to a reference to some known function **`pack()`**

In a case, there is no such known to the python interpreter state, it threw an exception mentioned above.

However, the object **`miFrame`**, being a row above that assigned to a **`tkinter.Frame`** instance, there is an instance-method present - the **`.pack()`**, that can be called, instead of an attempt to straight re-assign the **`miFrame`**, right after it's instantiation:

```
miFrame = Frame( root, width  = 500,
                       height = 400
                       )
miFrame.pack() #_____________________ .pack() is a Frame-class instance-method

Label( miFrame, text = "Hola alumnos de Python",
                fg   = "red",
                font = ( "Comic Sans MS", 18 )
                ).place( x = 100,
                         y = 200
                         )
```

Comment: Thanks! That was the problem